# Is it possible to create a "generic" function in Standard ML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml, mosml

I would like to create a function `remove_duplicates` that takes a `list` of any type (e.g. can be an `int list` or a `bool list` or a `int list list` or a `whatever list`) and returns the same list without duplicates, is this possible in Standard ML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is a function that takes a list of any type and returns the list without duplicates possible in Standard ML?

No.

To determine if one element is a duplicate of another, their values must be comparable. "Any type", or `'a` in Standard ML, is not comparable for equality. So while you cannot have a `val nub : 'a list -> 'a list` that removes duplicates, here are four alternative options:

1. What @qouify suggests, the built-in equality type `''a`, so anything you can use `=` on:

   ```
   val nub : ''a list -> ''a list
   ```
2. What @kopecs suggests, a function that takes an equality operator as parameter:

   ```
   val nub : ('a * 'a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
   ```

   Which is a generalisation of 1., since here, `nub op= : ''a list -> ''a list`. This solution is kind of neat since it lets you remove not only duplicates, but also redundant representatives of arbitrary equivalence classes, e.g. `nub (fn (x, y) => (x mod 3) = (y mod 3))` will only preserve integers that are distinct modulo 3. But its complexity is *O(n²)*. (-_- )ﾉ⌒┻━┻
3. Because it is *O(n²)*, [`nub` is considered harmful](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2015/02/nub-considered-harmful.html).

   As the article also suggests, the alternative is to use ordering rather than equality to reduce the complexity to *O(n log n)*. While in Haskell this means only changing the type class constraint:

   ```
   nub    :: Eq a  => [a] -> [a]
   nubOrd :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
   ```

   and adjusting the algorithm, it gets a little more complicated to express this constraint in SML. While we *do* have `''a` to represent `Eq a => a` (that we can use `=` on our input), we *don't* have a similar special syntax support for elements that can be compared as less/equal/greater, and we also don't have type classes. We *do* have the following built-in order type:

   ```
   datatype order = LESS | EQUAL | GREATER
   ```

   so if you like kopecs' solution, a variation with a better running time is:

   ```
   val nubOrd : ('a * 'a -> order) -> 'a list -> 'a list
   ```

   since it can use something like a mathematical set of previously seen elements, implemented using some kind of balanced search tree; *n* inserts each of complexity *O(log n)* takes a total of *O(n log n)* steps.
4. One of SML's winner features is its composable module system. Instead of using parametric polymorphism and feeding the function `nubOrd` with an order comparison function, you can create a module that takes another module as a parameter (a *functor*).

   First, let's define a *signature* for modules that represent ordering of types:

   ```
   signature ORD =
   sig
     type t
     val compare : t * t -> order
   end
   ```

   *(Notice that there isn't a `'` in front of `t`.)*

   This means that anyone could make a `struct ... end : ORD` by specifying a `t` and a corresponding `compare` function for `t`s. Many built-in types have pre-defined `compare` functions: *int* has `Int.compare` and *real* has `Real.compare`.

   Then, define a tree-based set data structure; I've used a binary search tree, and I've skipped most functions but the ones strictly necessary to perform this feat. Ideally you might extend the interface and use a better tree type, such as a self-balancing tree. *(Unfortunately, since you've tagged this Q&A both as SML/NJ and Moscow ML, I wasn't sure which module to use, since they extend the standard library in different ways when it comes to balanced trees.)*

   ```
   functor TreeSet (X : ORD) =
   struct
     type t = X.t
     datatype 'a tree = Leaf | Branch of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree

     val empty = Leaf

     fun member (x, Leaf) = false
       | member (x, Branch (left, y, right)) =
           case X.compare (x, y) of
                EQUAL => true
              | LESS => member (x, left)
              | GREATER => member (x, right)

     fun insert (x, Leaf) = Branch (Leaf, x, Leaf)
       | insert (x, Branch (left, y, right)) =
           case X.compare (x, y) of
                EQUAL => Branch (left, y, right)
              | LESS  => Branch (insert (x, left), y, right)
              | GREATER => Branch (left, y, insert (x, right))
   end
   ```

   Lastly, the `ListUtils` functor contains the `nubOrd` utility function. The functor takes a structure `X : ORD` just like the `TreeSet` functor does. It creates an `XSet` structure by specialising the `TreeSet` functor using the same ordering module. It then uses this `XSet` to *efficiently* keep a record of the elements it has seen before.

   ```
   functor ListUtils (X : ORD) =
   struct
     structure XSet = TreeSet(X)

     fun nubOrd (xs : X.t list) =
       let
         val init = ([], XSet.empty)
         fun go (x, (ys, seen)) =
           if XSet.member (x, seen)
             then (ys, seen)
             else (x::ys, XSet.insert (x, seen))
       in rev (#1 (foldl go init xs))
       end
   end
   ```

   Using this functor to remove duplicates in an `int list`:

   ```
   structure IntListUtils = ListUtils(struct
                                        type t = int
                                        val compare = Int.compare
                                      end)

   val example = IntListUtils.nubOrd [1,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,3,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2,1]
                                  (* [1,  2,  3,              4,      5] *)
   ```

   The purpose of all that mess is a `nubOrd` without a direct extra function parameter.

   Unfortunately, in order for this to extend to `int list list`, you need to create the `compare` function for that type, since unlike `Int.compare`, there isn't a generic one available in the standard library either. (This is where Haskell is a lot more ergonomic.)

   So you might go and write a generic, lexicographical list compare function: If you know how to compare two elements of type `'a`, you know how to compare two lists of those, no matter what the element type is:

   ```
   fun listCompare _ ([], []) = EQUAL   (* empty lists are equal *)
     | listCompare _ ([], ys) = LESS    (* empty is always smaller than non-empty *)
     | listCompare _ (xs, []) = GREATER (* empty is always smaller than non-empty *)
     | listCompare compare (x::xs, y::ys) =
         case compare (x, y) of
              EQUAL => listCompare compare (xs, ys)
            | LESS => LESS
            | GREATER => GREATER
   ```

   And now,

   ```
   structure IntListListUtils = ListUtils(struct
                                            type t = int list
                                            val compare = listCompare Int.compare
                                          end)
   val example2 = IntListListUtils.nubOrd [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,2],[1,2,3]]
                                       (* [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,2]] *)
   ```

   So even though `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,2]` contain duplicates, they are not `EQUAL` when you `compare` them. But the third element *is* `EQUAL` to the first one, and so it gets removed as a duplicate.

Some last observations:

- You may consider that even though each `compare` is only run *O(log n)* times, a single `compare` for some complex data structure, such as a `(whatever * int) list list` may still be expensive. So another improvement you can make here is to cache the result of every `compare` output, which is actually what Haskell's [`nubOrdOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.4/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:nubOrdOn) operator does. ┳━┳ ヽ(ಠل͜ಠ)ﾉ
- The functor approach is used extensively in [Jane Street's OCaml Base library](https://opensource.janestreet.com/base/). The quick solution was to pass around an `'a * 'a -> order` function around every single time you `nub` something. One moral, though, is that while the module system does add verbosity, if you provide enough of this machinery in a standard library, it will become quite convenient.
- If you think the improvement from *O(n²)* to *O(n log n)* is not enough, consider Fritz Henglein's [Generic top-down discrimination for sorting and partitioning in linear time](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/utgp/school/henglein2012c.pdf) (2012) and Edward Kmett's Haskell [discrimination package's `nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination-0.4/docs/Data-Discrimination-Grouping.html#v:nub) for a *O(n)* `nub`.

Comment: Is it such a big deal that `nub` has a quadratic runtime? Does all our software need to run at optimal speeds?

Comment: @ThorkilVærge: Yes, and no.

Comment: Nit: SML does not have a higher-order module system, only a first-order one.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: Thanks for pointing that out. :) I've used the term "higher-order module" as an analogue to "higher-order functions". I suppose that you don't ever create `functor`s that take arbitrary modules as parameter, but always concrete modules.

Comment: @SimonShine, yes, and you can't do more than that in plain SML. Functors cannot take functors as arguments.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: Considering your work with 1ML, was that ever explored by you or anyone else?

Comment: @SimonShine, higher-order functors have always been available in SML/NJ, in Moscow ML since v2, and in a few other SMLs. They just aren't standardised, and all these extensions differ. Back in 2007 or so, I created a proposal for Successor ML. FWIW, OCaml has HO functors, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible in SML through use of parametric polymorphism. You want a function of most general type `'a list -> 'a list` where `'a` is a type variable (i.e., variable that ranges over types) that would be read as alpha.

For some more concrete examples of how you might apply this (the explicit type variable after `fun` is optional):

```ml
fun 'a id (x : 'a) : 'a = x
```

Here we have the identity function with type `'a -> 'a`.

We can declare similar functions with some degree of specialisation of the types, for instance

```ml
fun map _ [] = []
  | map f (x::xs) = f x :: map f xs
```

Where `map` has most general type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`, i.e, takes two curried arguments, one with some function type and another with some list type (agrees with function's domain) and returns a new list with type given by the codomain of the function.

For your specific problem you'll probably also want to take an equality function in order to determine what is a "duplicate" or you'll probably restrict yourself to "equality types" (types that can be compared with `op=`, represented by type variables with two leading apostrophes, e.g., `''a`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes sml provides *polymorphism* to do such things.  In many cases you actually don't care for the type of the item in your lists (or other structures).  For instance this function checks (already present in the `List` structure) for the existence of an item in a list:

```ml
fun exists _ [] = false
  | exists x (y :: l) = x = y orelse exists x l
```

Such function works for any type of list as long as the equal operator is defined for this type (such type is called an equality type).  You can do the same for `remove_duplicates`.  In order to work with list of items of non equality types you will have to give `remove_duplicates` an additional function that checks if two items are equal.